# Why do accuracy and MacroF1 decreases and AUC increases when I go from transductive to inductive classification?

Tags: classification, unbalanced-classes, metric

I have two experiments with the goal of binary classification with multi-layer perceptron. Train, validation, and test set are the same in both. The only difference is that in the 1st experiment, the min-max scaler fits on the whole dataset (train validation test, although they are not seen in the training process - transductive setting). In the 2nd experiment, the min-max scaler fits on the training, and the validation and test sets will be transformed with the fitted scaler (inductive setting). In order to see the effect of this change, I compared the best results that classifiers achieve on the test set (I know that the right way is to choose it with the validation set, I just wanted to analyze the situation), accuracy, and f1 macro in the second experiment decreases but ROC AUC increases. I can not interpret the results. What is the meaning behind this change? It should be also noted that the dataset is highly imbalanced (12:1).

Comment: One of the things that can happen if you’re mad max scaler set on the training is that it is truncating your data set. So that would mean that it is clamping some of the extreme mall test values before running them through your classifier. I’m not exactly sure why this is having its particular affect on your accuracy and area under the curve.

Comment: F1 and accuracy depends on a threshold selection while AUC sweeps through all possible thresholds. I don't think comparing these is going to be easy.